# How can I align a RelativeLayout containing a ListView in between other two RelativeLayout on each side horizontally?

Tags: android, listview, imageview, android-relativelayout

I am including the layout.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/grey" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@id/layout_content_magthumb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/grey" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@id/content_thumb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_large"
            android:src="@drawable/cover1" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@id/layout_content_list"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/layout_content_magthumb"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/layout_content_description"
        android:background="@color/yellow" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@id/list_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        </ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@id/layout_content_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_large"
            android:src="@drawable/cover2" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem that I am facing is that whenever I include the ListView in the layout it takes up the whole layout except the layout space for left RelativeLayout.

Please suggest.

Answer (score -1):

Try assigning a weight of `0.1` or something else to the `RelativeLayout` that contains the `ListView`:

```
android:layout_weight="0.1"
```

Comment: Can you try with a `LinearLayout` where orientation is `horzontal` and weight specified as above. I had the same problem a few days back and found this to work for me.

Comment: Well I found a way, but I have a point to bring up. Firstly I had to set the layout_width of the listview to 200dp or (what ever you like). If you set the layout_width of the listview to wrap_content it will set it as fill_parent. Next setting the attribute layout_toRightOf relativeLayout of the listview to the id of the left relative layout. And about the left relative layout I am setting the android:layout_toRightOf="@id/layout_content_list"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true".